# where to check out the screen detached command line application crash log on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, crash, gnu-screen

So, I was running some application with the following command line after SSHing into my server, and after then detached the window by ctrl+a ctrl+d:

```
SCREEN /bin/bash -c php index.php -whatever > /logs/inst1_20151020.log
```

Then I encountered some system disfunction complaint, so I SSHed into the server, and found my command line application exited abnormally by using the following command line:

```
ps -aux | grep php
```

So, I'd checked the /var/log/ folder, and didn't find any useful information anywhere. I was trying to figure out what is the cause for this abnormal crash, where can I find the crash log?

Here is my detailed web server information:

```
lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some missing detail: there is no `SCREEN` executable as such.  The executable is lowercase `screen` (though it forks and names one process [`"SCREEN"`](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Debug)).

But assuming that the command was meant as

```
screen /bin/bash -c php index.php -whatever > /logs/inst1_20151020.log
```

then the log-file would be in the directory `/logs`, and contain only the output from *starting* the bash command (since the `>` operator is run *before* running bash).  More likely than not, *that* file is empty.

Comment: Great explanation.